# Error inflating class fragment after remove and import google-play-service_lib project

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, fragment, android-inflate

I have searched many related question, but still have no clue to solve it. 
Before I deleted the google_play_service_lib project, everthing is fine, BUT after i deleted it, and import it again, the error just happened...

Here are the codes:

about_frag.XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/location_map"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AboutFragment.java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_frag, container, false);
    sc = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
    sc.setOnTouchListener(null);

    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.about_text);
    tv.setText(R.string.esoft_about);
    MainFragmentActivity.instance().fixedTextSize(tv);

    return view;
}
```

the Error log

```
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013): Process: mypackage, PID: 7013
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Error inflating class fragment
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at esoft.com.edm.AboutFragment.onCreateView(AboutFragment.java:33)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:871)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java: 431)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:895)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:772)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1234)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-19 15:55:09.562: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at java.lang.refle
```

BTW, when i delete the fragment from XML, the program work perfectly...
hope is not an old question...

Comment: where is you R.id.scrollView1 and R.id.about_text in which layout?

Comment: Dear all sorry for missing some words, at first i have included the google-play-service_lib definitely, and it works fine, but after i remove it and import it as the lib, the error came out...

Comment: So i am telling you that is it properly imported as Green Mark?

Comment: What is your 48 line??

Comment: Have you added the `support-v4` library in your project?

Comment: Show how you are initializing the MapFragment ?

Comment: Its a SupportMapFragment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you receiving the `Error inflating class fragment` error then you have some kind of problem with the way you reference the needed libraries. Take a look at this blog post i wrote and go over the first 4 section of it:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

If you have committed this, and still have a problem.
Try to re-download and move the `google-play-service` lib to a different location where it's path would be shorter and then reference it again.

Comment: Thanks for replay, i think you are right, but after i remove it the google play service, and re-download it, the lib file in google-play-services_lib project is empty...

Comment: It's sound weird, try the redownload part again, there is no reason the folder will be empty.

Comment: finially, I solved it by using Google_Play_Service_froyo...Cheers man!